# Get Username of Current Realm SyncUser in Swift

Tags: realm

*Realm Swift 2.0.2, Swift 3*

I'd like to display the username of the current Realm `SyncUser` in my UI. I know I can get the unique ID of a user like this:

```
let user = SyncUser.all().first
print(user?.identity) //a7f84g203fd18... etc.
```

...but is there a way to get the user's username? I don't see anything in the docs about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to get username from `SyncUser`: `SyncUser` doesn't have username at all, it's just one of the credentials that could be used for authentication.

There is also a related issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to save to `UserDefaults` the user's email/username when they sign up:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(self.email.text!, forKey: "userEmail")
```

...and then reference it later where I need it in my app:

```
//Show username/email
accountStatus.text = defaults.string(forKey: "userEmail")
```